# Mixing php and javascript -- under what conditions?

Tags: php, javascript

Under what conditions can I put PHP into Javascript code?  Is it always ok? Is it just a bad idea? I am surprised I have not seen it more.

For example, I came across this..

```
$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: '<?php echo $thumb_height/$thumb_width;?>', onSelectChange:preview});
```

..which was in an onpage script element.  I'm not so experienced, but I was just surprised that I had never seen mixed js/php before.  But can you put PHP in .js files as well?  If I set the file extension to .php, will the file be parsed?

Comment: The title and the actual question do not match, not even close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put PHP code into `*.js` files but you need to tell the webserver to also execute the PHP interpreter on `*.js` files. Something like this should be in your `httpd.conf`

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .js

    ...
</IfModule>
```

A better solution is to just rename your `*.js` files to `*.js.php` or just `*.php`. The browsers won't mind and the PHP interpreter will also get executed on those.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing JS with PHP is usually avoided due to debugging difficulties and/or poor code readability (like mixing PHP with HTML). It is, however, possible. But a safer approach might be to pass the PHP value to a function, or set the PHP value to a global JS variable, and use that instead. Maybe something like this:

```
    //JS code
    var value = <?php echo ($thumb_height/$thumb_width);?>

....

    $('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: value, onSelectChange:preview});
```

This way it will be much easier to read. Have a great day.

Comment: I disagree. PHP is not considered a template engine. And if mixing it with HTML and/or JS is possible, that doesn't mean that it's a must.

Comment: You need more experience and/or research. PHP is a leading template engine nowadays. It can do the same what Smarty or XSLT does but without Smarty or XSLT. Why use anything else? Why mixing PHP with HTML is a no-no but Smarty with HTML is all right? What's the difference?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to share some links on this topic, since obviously I need more experience?...And if you don't know the answer to your own question, I think you are the one who needs more experience and/or research.

Comment: Zend framework for example http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link. But I think they use that first script as a basic example. If you read further, they offer more information on using alternate template systems.

Comment: Sure, there are *alternate* ones. Additional. Supplementary. They have support for all of them. I've never said that PHP is *the only* template engine. I have said it is a leading one. It is.

Comment: Got any *certain* objections against PHP as a template engine?

Comment: No, I don't have objections. I just don't agree with the idea that PHP's main purpose is to be a template engine. And that's what you seem to emphasize.

Comment: oh, I didn't mean that PHP's main purpose is to be a template engine. PHP's main purpose remains the same - to be the core business logic language. *Besides that* it is the best template engine also.

Comment: Nice link but I personally prefer smarty for my templates and I personally don't know anybody who would write templates with PHP. It's just terrible to read.

Comment: I agree. That's what i was saying all along :)

Answer (score 0):

> Under what conditions can I put PHP into Javascript code?

Under no conditions. That would be impossible and useless.
You can can put only contrary - JS code into PHP. 
In other words you can make PHP output whatever *text*, which can be valid HTML, JS, XML, whatever.
Once sent to the browser, this text will be interpreted accordingly, **but with not a trace of PHP in it**.

It is always OK as long as PHP represents display logic only.

So, you put PHP in .js files only if it would be actually PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented is a very reasonable way to dynamically generate javascript in the web page returned by the web server.

So, for example, if $thumb_height was 100 and $thumb_width was 10, the web server would return a web page containing the following javascript:

$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: '10', onSelectChange:preview});

If, on another call to the page, $thumb_height was 24 and $thumb_width was 6 the web page returned by the server would be:

$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: '4', onSelectChange:preview});

You can use php to dynamically generate any part of a web page, both the html and the javascript.