# Add a <?php text ?> in a code

Tags: php, text, replace, echo

I have this code

```
if(!document.getElementById('slider_cmp'))
{
    var toolTip = document.createElement("div");
    toolTip.className = "cmp_tips";
    toolTip.id = "cmp_tips";
    toolTip.style.position = "absolute";
    toolTip.style.top =  '145px';
    toolTip.style.left = '50px';
    toolTip.style.display = "none";
    toolTip.style.zIndex = 9999;        
    toolTip.innerHTML = "I NEED TEXT HERE";
    document.body.appendChild(toolTip);
    var sliderDiv = document.createElement("div");
    sliderDiv.className = "slide-out-div";
    sliderDiv.id = "slider_cmp";
    sliderDiv.style.display = "none";
    var handler = '<div id="clickme"></div><div id="slidecontent"></div>';
    sliderDiv.innerHTML= handler;
    document.body.appendChild(sliderDiv);       
    if(cmpLastCat > 0)
    {
```

I need to put a `<?php echo something ?>` instead of `"I NEED TEXT HERE"` in this code... can somebody please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: If this code snipped is from a `*.js` file, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632744/mixing-php-and-javascript-under-what-conditions/9632843#9632843

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JavaScript is within in a PHP-file, you could simply do:

```
toolTip.innerHTML = "<?php echo $someVariableToPrint; ?>";
```

The PHP-snippet will be evaluated on the server prior to sending the page to client, so what the client recieves is:

```
toolTip.innerHTML = "The text in the variable";
```

**Update**

Based on the additional info given in your comment, your code would be:

```
toolTip.innerHTML = "<?php echo CBTxt::_('text here'); ?>";
```

Comment: Hi What I need to add is -

<?php echo CBTxt::_ ( 'text here' ); ?>

Can I add this there?

Comment: @AlexandruVlas Not sure I understand what you mean? If you want to print some PHP-variable as the text, you simply replace your line `toolTip.innerHTML = "I NEED TEXT HERE";` with my line above. You will of course have to change the variable name $someVariableToPrint to the name of the variable that contain the text that you want to print.

Comment: @AlexandruVlas `toolTip.innerHTML = "<?php echo  CBTxt::_ ( 'text here' ); ?>";` should do it. See my updated answer!

Comment: Hm... I tried it but it doesn't accept it...
I'm looking in source code and it put's the code as a "comment"... <!--?php echo CBTxt::_('texthere'); ?-->

Comment: @AlexandruVlas How do you mean "it doesn't accept it"? Get any JS- or PHP-errors?

Comment: @AlexandruVlas That looks weird, it has been made into an HTML-comment. What happens if you put a `console.log(toolTip.innerHTML);` just after you have assigned toolTip.innerHTML. What do you get in your console?

Comment: Hi

this is what it gives in Console: 

<!--?php echo CBTxt::_ ( 'text here' ); ?-->
8event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

Comment: @AlexandruVlas (1) Is the JS-code placed in a *.php-file, or a *.js-file? (2) Off topic: You can get rid of the `event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future` warning by upgrading to the most recent version of jQuery.

Comment: Hi, it is a .js file. 
Sorry I'm not too good in this stuff, is it "easy" to get rid of the "event.layerX and event.layerY", if I leave everything like it is now will my site be broken after "in near future" that will be removed from engine? Thank you. Cheers

Comment: PS. I can send you the file if you want?

Comment: @AlexandruVlas If it is in a *.js-file it won't work, because the web server won't run the PHP-code prior to sending the file to the client. You can rename the file to .php instead of .js, to make the web server run the PHP code first. Remember to modify the URL in your script-tag as well.

Comment: @AlexandruVlas About the warning, if you are using jQuery, make sure to use the most recent version (1.7.1 at the moment), and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
toolTip.innerHTML = "<?php echo 'text' ?>";
```

Comment: Hi What I need to add is -

<?php echo CBTxt::_ ( 'text here' ); ?>

Can I add this there?

Comment: Is CBTxt::_ a function? Where's that defined?

Comment: My site is in 2 language... CBTxt responds for the translation of the "text here" in more languages...